# Finding the largest value in an array and efficiency of code

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, space-complexity

I want to know if my concept and understanding of the code is correct or not! Here, at first, I set the last number as the max, and then I am using another for loop to compare each value to all other values to find the largest value right? Also is the runtime of this is O(n^2) since here two for loop is used? I know there exists a better linear solution(O(n)) but I want to manually see and check how much time it will take to execute it and also trying to compare the efficiency between two. I also do not know what is the space complexity of this code. Any further explanation will be greatly appreciated.

```
 /*The following code will return the largest value in an array of non-negative integers */
int CompareToAll (int array[], int n)
{
    int i, j;
    bool isMax;

    if (n <= 0)
       return -1;

    for (i = n-1; i > 0; i--) {
         isMax = true;
         for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (array[j] > array[i]) {
               isMax = false;
               break;
            }
         }
            if (isMax) break;
         }

         return array[i];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, pessimistic complexity of this algorithm is `O(n^2)`, optimistic is `O(n)`.

### Optimistic

First/last element is the largest. In such case only single pass (by either loop) will be done so each element will be visited only once.

### Pessimistic

Middle element is the largest. In such case outer loop will run `n/2` times and inner loop `n/2` times until the half of the array is reached by the outer loop.

This gives us `1/2 * n * 1/2 * n` which is `O(n^2)` as the constant does not matter.

This is also your average as we have no assumption about your data to use here.

### O(n) solution

Go from either end of the array and keep the maximum value seen and switch if bigger is found. Return biggest after all elements were visited.

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity is `O(n^2)` in average case and in the worst case.

Note that this algo has the best case with complexity `O(n)` (when ``isMax is found at the first iteration(s)).

Space compexity is `O(1)` - you use only constant space not depending on array size

Answer (score 0):

As you're using an array, the notation for the space complexity would be equivalent to the time complexity. Hence In your case the space complexity would be O(n^2).

An O(n) algorithm would be alongside with its comparison for array lengths upto 1000000 in nanoseconds would be: However, the timing seems to not be working correctly as it varies too much. But yeah, it should be something like this.

### Time taken with array size 10
O(n) algorithm 0 nanoseconds
O(n^2) algorithm 0 nanoseconds

### Time taken with array size 100
O(n) algorithm 0 microseconds
O(n^2) algorithm 0 microseconds

### Time taken with array size 1000
O(n) algorithm 4 microseconds
O(n^2) algorithm 5 microseconds

### Time taken with array size 10000
O(n) algorithm 39 microseconds
O(n^2) algorithm 48 microseconds

### Time taken with array size 100000
O(n) algorithm 2293 microseconds
O(n^2) algorithm 4189 microseconds

### Time taken with array size 1000000
O(n) algorithm 3271 microseconds
O(n^2) algorithm 9715 microseconds

```
    #include <algorithm> 
    #include <chrono> 
    #include <iostream> 
    using namespace std; 
    using namespace std::chrono; 

    // O(n)
    int findMax(int arr[], int n){

        int maxindex = -1; // to return the position of the maximum value 
        int maxvalue = -1; // // negative hence smallest number amongst positive integers 
        for(int i=0 ; i< n ; i++ ){
    if(arr[i] > maxvalue) {
        maxvalue = arr[i]; // storing max value for next comparison 
        maxindex = i ; //stopring max index to return 
    }
} 
        if( maxindex<0 ) return -1; //list full of negative values 
        return arr[maxindex];

    }

    // O(n^2)
    int CompareToAll(int array[], int n) // your algorithm 
    {
int i, j;
bool isMax;
if (n <= 0)
   return -1;
for (i = n-1; i > 0; i--) {
     isMax = true;
     for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (array[j] > array[i]) {
           isMax = false;
           break;
        }
     }
             if (isMax) break;
        }

        return array[i];
    }





    int main()
    {
for (int i=10 ; i<=1000000; i=i*10){
int arr[i];

for(int j =0 ; j<i ; j++ ){
    arr[j] = j*2 ; 
}
cout<< endl << "Time taken with array size " << i; 
// Get starting timepoint 
auto start_n = high_resolution_clock::now(); 
findMax(arr,i); 
auto end_n = high_resolution_clock::now();
cout<<endl;
auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(end_n - start_n); 
cout<<"O(n) algorithm " <<duration.count() << " nanoseconds"<<endl;


// Get starting timepoint 
auto start = high_resolution_clock::now(); 
CompareToAll(arr,i);
auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();
auto duration2 = duration_cast<microseconds>(end - start); 
cout<< "O(n^2) algorithm " << duration2.count()<< " nanoseconds";
cout<<endl; 
cout<< "------------------";
};
return 0;
    }
```